# Why can't I reference the accessible members in a base class from within XML documentation comment tags in a derived class?

Tags: c#, code-documentation

Say I have this:

```
internal abstract class Animal
{
    internal bool IsExtinct { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class WoollyMammoth : Animal
{
    internal int WeightLbs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Construct a new instance with <see cref="IsExtinct"/> // this throws an error "XML comment has cref attribute 'IsExtinct' that could not be resolved".
    /// set to "true" and <see cref="WeightLbs"/> // this works just fine.
    /// initialized to 0.
    /// </summary>
    WoollyMammoth()
    {
        // no problem with either of these, of course.
        IsExtinct = true; 
        WeightLbs = 0;
    }
}
```

Why am I getting an error when trying to reference the `IsExtinct` property, defined in the base class, from the `<see/>` XML comment tag?  I can access properties that are defined in the derived class, like `WeightLbs`.

Comment: Is the property maybe private?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To reference a base class symbol, use a qualified name: `<see cref="Animal.IsExtinct"/>`.

There is no particular reason why this should be required. The Roslyn code base contains a test which specifically tests that base class symbols are not found [(`CrefTests.TypeScope4`)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/282679022963c053b7c2553b8e18faa6836e770b/src/Compilers/CSharp/Test/Symbol/DocumentationComments/CrefTests.cs#L448) which mentions that the reason is simply is because that is what the previous compiler did:

> `// As in dev11, we ignore the inherited method symbol.`

It looks like a historic accident, and since the workaround is trivial it's unlikely to be changed.